# How to change the Zen theme to a single sidebar layout?

Tags: theming

I'm using [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) (version 7.x-5.5) as a base theme.

The problem is that it's showing with 2 sidebars layout. I searched in the documentation but I didn't find a way to change it to 1 sidebar layout (with main content of course ).

I changed the SCSS files in `_responsive.scss`, but nothing changed.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

In page.tpl.php, at line 109 and line 110, delete the sidebar you don't want

In style.css change this class
.region-sidebar-second{
float:left;width:20%;margin-left:0%;margin-right:-20%
}

to be
.region-sidebar-second{
float:left;width:20%;margin-left:0%;margin-right:-20%;display:none;//add a display:none
}

and change .two-sidebars #content {
float: left;
width: 60%;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: -80%;
}

to be

.two-sidebars #content {
float: left;
width: 80%; //change 60% to 80%
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: -80%;
}

Comment: i did but there's no difference

Comment: I updated my answer, please check again to see if it works

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi Have you got less compiler set up and watching your scss folder?

Comment: no i didn't but im newby in sass and as i said i need a step by step tutorial

Comment: @ZhuolinLi give me some time to test it, i hope that will not influence the responsive design of Zen

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed sass and compass?  As I understand zen 5.5, the scss files are not executed until compass recognizes a change in the sass (.scss) files and then regenerates the resulting css, which is what your browser is actually using to display your page.  As far as I can see, compass does this by putting the new css in the styles.css file.  Check the date on your styles.css file (listed in yourzensubtheme/css) and see if it has been updated.  If not, then you may be still running the old configuration and that's why you don't see any changes.

Oh, and don't forget to clear all caches so that Drupal knows that something has changed.